# Vuetify - v-badge with huge number

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some issue using `v-badge` and `v-tab` with huge number in `v-badge`.

I found a workaround in css to `width: auto;` nicely `v-badge` size (to use huge numbers), but now it is overlapping my `v-tab` content because it's expanding in the wrong direction.

How can I avoid my `v-badge` content overlapping my `v-tab` content ?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeYOad)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-tabs fixed-tabs>
      <v-tab
        v-for="n in 3"
        :key="n"
      >
        <v-badge color="secondary">
          <span>Test</span>
          <span slot="badge"> 15000 </span>
        </v-badge>
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.v-badge__badge{
  width:auto;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'  
})
```

Comment: Abbreviate the numbers

Comment: A helper library: https://github.com/domharrington/js-number-abbreviate

Comment: Thanks for sharing this lib. Badge will mostly contains 3 digits numbers (ex: 125), sometimes 4 or 5 digits and I will use your lib. But will not resolve main case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have any specific reason to use the `v-badge` for this? I think `v-badge` is not meant to be used in the way you are using it. It has a fixed width and a height. Have you considered using a `v-chip`? As I see, that's the one which fits to your requirement well.

However, if you insist on using a `v-badge`, you can do a little hack and get them to align properly by adding an icon in between your number and text.

```
<v-badge left color="secondary">
    <span slot="badge"> 15000 </span>
    <span slot="default">Test</span>
    <v-icon large color="grey lighten-1" >&nbsp;</v-icon>
</v-badge>
```

[CodePen - v-badge](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXdQqX)

You can also use `v-chip` to do this. I think this is the better way.

```
<v-chip color="grey"> 1500000 </v-chip>
<div>test</div>
```

[CodePen v-badge](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXbyEd)

Hope it helps! Feel free to ask any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

just make a badge with css:

```
.myBadge {
  background-color: lightgrey; 
  border-radius: 90px; 
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 20px;
  color: white; 
  margin-left: 8px; 
  padding: .5px 3px .5px 3px; 
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```